# Adding custom Field to doctrine object in Controller

Tags: object, doctrine, twig

I have a symfony2 Project with an Account entity. It has two attributes id and description.

In my Controller i want to enrich my doctrine Objekts with a further field called name. This property will not be persisted and is only used in my twig template. In twig i want to use {{Account.name}}.

How can i assign values to my objects in my controller that can be used in the twig file?

Thanks, greets mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, its actually so easy :-)

i can simply add

```
$entity->myproperty = "whatever i want";
```

and then in my twig template i use

```
{{entity.myname}}
```

thanks anyway... i did not know that i can assing properties to my objects like this.